# How to make an index and drop an index

Tags: mysql

I will be doing this every week. Copying table name change the name through PHP and MySQLi. I know how to do that.

Drop all the indexes through PHP and MySQL. Then using PHP and MySQLI make appropriate edits to the new table, and then creating the same indexes through PHP and MySQLI.

I googled how to do this and even went to Stackoverflow not finding anything to help me.

Can you please show me how to drop and add indexed?
The column region is the one I want to be indexed.

Sample database

| id | region | id1_players | id2_players |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 103 | 20 | 5 |
| 3 | 104 | 7 | 5 |
| 4 | 100 | 11 | 2 |
| 5 | 102 | 6 | 9 |
| 6 | 102 | 7 | 2 |
| 7 | 100 | 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 103 | 6 | 2 |
| 9 | 100 | 6 | 7 |

PHP

```
<?php
     $link=mysqli_connect(db_host,db_user,db_pass,db_pools);
     mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8")
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to reINDEX the TABLE, unless you want different INDEXes, or you've DROPped the TABLE.

Comment: I am developing the website right now for myself. 
I will be updating a table with every member every week. When you drop all the indexes it speeds up the updating in the database. That is why I am dropping all the indexes then creating all the indexes again.  I have no idea how many members I will be having. I just playing it safe. Thank you for help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
//Drop index
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` DROP INDEX `column_list`";
$result = $link->query($sql);
//add index
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` ADD INDEX index_name (column_list)";
$result = $link->query($sql);
```